# Custom Action works fine on default view but not other?

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, ribbon

I have a list. Over in Visual Studio 2010, I have a customized replacement for the "Delete Item" button in the Ribbon, my customized version fires off a workflow, and some other stuff. In order to get the button to display for this list and not every list, in Elements.xml, I had to use RegistrationId, as follows:

```
  <CustomAction 
    Id="ReplaceDeleteBtn"
    Title="Replace default button"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
    RegistrationId="{12345678-ABCD-EF01-909B-49F8D34C0000}"
    RegistrationType="List">
```

I found RegistrationId to be the only reliable way to get my replacement Delete button to appear in the ribbon. Using a numeric identifier (e.g. "101") didn't work as desired. Using the GUID of the list did.

Now here is the real question: When I say it "appears as desired", I mean *within the default view for the list*. There are other views for the list, but the button does not appear there. Argh. I tried using the GUID of the view for RegistrationId. Nope. I have to use the GUID of the list itself, but then the button only works for the default view of that list.

Anybody have any experience with this issue? Neither Google nor Bing turned up anything obvious.

Comment: Could you explain what are all the other views you need your button to be displayed? Are you asking to restrict your button for only one list?

Comment: Yes, my button is restricted to only one list. But that's the royal pain. A List and a View are two different things. Each List has 1+ Views, with one particular view being blessed as the Default. The RegistrationId used to set a particular list is the List guid, but not the View guid. So, there is no apparent way to get a button to appear on all Views for the desired List. Or possibly, it's a bug and MS's intent was for it to work on all Views.